# How can I separate my pics and videos so only the one the user post is displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to write an if else statement so that when a users post a photo only the photo is displayed the same goes for videos. Right now if a users post a video a blank photo will be displayed under the video as well. My code is below. I know it has something to do with the lines:

```
<%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
<%= video_tag @post.video.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/mp4" %>
```

I just don't know what the best way is to only show the one the user is posting.

**Post/Show.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-med-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading center">
            <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
            <%= video_tag @post.video.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/mp4" %>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= @post.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= @post.user.name if @post.user %></strong></p>

    <% if @post.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_post_path(@post) do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        Edit
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :video %>
    <%= f.file_field :video %>
  </div></br>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-danger btn-md" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so a user has both videos and photos in a post?

Comment: @rico_mac yes, the form gives them the ability to select to post a video or a picture. If they upload a pic and submit it a black screen for the video will be displayed underneath as well and vice versa. Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you could try this...

```
<% if @post.respond_to?(:image) %>
  <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
end
<% if @post.respond_to?(:video) %>
  <%= image_tag @post.video.url(:medium), controls: true, type: "video/mp4"  %>
end
```

You are basically checking for the existence of the particular attribute. You are saying, if it is here, if it exists, then display it.

Or you could try this

```
<% if @post.image.url != nil %>
   <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
.........(repeat for other attributes)
<% end %>
```

or this

```
 <% unless @post.image.url == nil %>
       <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
 <% end %>
```

see  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) for more info.

There are many ways to achieve what you want. this kind of thing is one of the fundamental concepts of programming.

Comment: I tried this. However, now it just shows the text "show image show video" in its place. Am I missing something? Thanks!

<% if @post.respond_to?(:image) %>
       show image
   <% end %>

   <% if @post.respond_to?(:video) %>
       show video
   <% end %>

Comment: @Annette yes. where i said 'show image', i meant 'use the code that displays the image.

Comment: Thank you! I completely understand now. Thank you for the link as well. I cannot vote up yet however, I accepted the answer.

Comment: @Annette no problem. I am glad I could help. It was only a few months ago I was asking the exact same questions. you will be amazed how quickly you pick things up.